# Java - Tree map.Суть задачи, в том чтобы посчитать % от всей вводимой строки каждого символа строки. В MAP1 не сохраняются все карты

Tags: java

```
 Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=in.nextLine();

   String [] mas_s =s.split("");
     String st;
  Map<Float,String> MAP1 = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i=0;i<mas_s.length;i++) {
       if (!MAP1.containsValue(mas_s[i])) {
      {      st = s.replaceAll(mas_s[i], "");
            MAP1.put((float)(mas_s.length-st.length())/(float)mas_s.length,mas_s[i]);
```

}

Comment: при большой строке сохраняется 3-4 символа а то и меньше, а при маленькой все работает нормально

Comment: кмк строка "ab" не очень длинная, но вызывает описанную проблему.

Comment: Наверно так хотели https://ideone.com/FV5n44

Comment: суть в том, что TreeMap сортирует по ключу? поэтому я хочу сделать чтоб ключ имел тип Float. У меня есть код где ключ -String, а значение Float,он работает , но там возникает проблема с сортировкой по значению

Comment: И не понятно как Вы процент считаете.

Comment: % символа = количество символа  умножить на  длину строки и разделить на  100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно моя ошибка была в том, что в цикле я пытался сохранить значения с одинаковым ключом (т.к. вероятности встречи того или иного символа могли совпадать), что категорический не возможно для Map(все ключи должны быть уникальны), поэтому TreeMap сохранял из всех карт с одинаковыми ключами только одну